# HTML5 <video> tag: RTMP streaming without Flash?

Tags: html, flash, video

I am building a video-site for long lecture recordings. So a streaming server is a must. We only have to support newest browsers, which support the HTML5 `<video>` tag. So when the stream is done via RTMP protocol (Red5 server for example), will clients have to have adobe flash installed or is a browser capable of the `<video>` tag enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that for a simple video streaming service (for  [VOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_on_demand)) you are not forced to use a [streaming server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_streaming_media_systems) (like AMS, Wowza, Red5, ...) just a HTTP server (like Apache, nginx, ...) with a good configuration and some special modules (like nginx [ngx_http_mp4_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html), [H264 Streaming Module for Apache](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/wiki/Mod-H264-Streaming-Apache-Version2), ...) can do the job because it can provide a HTTP stream available for Flash Player and HTML5.

So for your question, you should know that to play an RTMP stream on a browser, you should have Flash Player, HTML5 can not play it. That's why you have to provide a HTTP stream for HTML5 based video player. After that, you can use a Flash to HTML5 fallback or the inverse.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified a lot!

Comment: does all this i have to open up a upstream to rtmp server and then downstream it to http server and save it into a file after that a client browser can recieve stream on real time by sending start offset and end offset for small chunk of video stream Am i missing something or i am totally wrong here ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not clear what this answer says. Do my users need to have Flash installed to view an RTMP streaming video? Yes or no? Also, has anything changed now in 2019?

Comment: @mike Yes, to play an RTMP stream inside a web page the user should use Flash Player.

Comment: Thank you @akmozo. Looks like the video hosting provider we user for webinars has an RTMP option, but that only applies to the person uploading the video in that case because then our hosting provider still distributes it over HLS to users computers, so the end user doesn't need Flash installed to view the video and can use an HTML5 player.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else ends up here looking for a non-Flash solution for a non-http-based protocol i.e. RTSP (beware that OP asks for RTMP) here's a  solution https://github.com/Streamedian/html5_rtsp_player.